# Combine two line charts into one in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, chart.js

## What I have

I've created 2 graphs like shown in the first image below. I need these 2 graphs to be perfectly aligned on the 0 axis (which is shown in the section below).

[image]

## Wanted result

In the image below, the graphs are perfectly aligned and should therefore contain 2 different datasets. One should be placed on the left grid and the other one on the right grid.

[image]

## The options I thought of

I have not seen a way to implement this in ChartJS. Therefore, I thought of some possible solutions that could solve this issue in a different way.

1. Because both datasets don't have negative values, I *could* convert the left dataset to negative values (on the x-axis). The downside is that the range would be incorrect. Also, this would give issues with the popup message if you hover your mouse on a value.
2. Maybe, two `canvas` objects can be combined that could result in the **wanted result**

## Question

Is there a way to achieve the **wanted result** within ChartJS? Or can I perform some wizardry to combine two charts nicely into one? Or should I move to the D3.js library for this particular graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to "nicely" implement this. I've changed the source code of the ChartJS library to implement this.

This method uses 2 different graphs that render in 2 different `canvas` objects. These `canvas` objects are placed side-by-side to let it look like one graph.

This is my result (The code in here is not exactly like the graph in the picture because I changed it to my specific needs).

[image]

I've added a custom variable in the `options.layout` category named `sidePadding`.

The code of creating the graph:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById(this.element), {
         type: 'scatter',
         data: {
             datasets: [{
                 borderColor: this.lineColor,
                 borderWidth: 1,
                 pointBackgroundColor: '#000',
                 pointBorderColor: '#000',
                 pointRadius: 0,
                 fill: false,
                 tension: 0,
                 showLine: true,
                 data: [],
             }],
         },
         options: {
             aspectRatio: 0.3,
             maintainAspectRatio: false,
             responsive: true,
             layout: {
                 sidePadding: {
                     left: 3,
                     right: -3,
                 }
             }
         }
     });
```

The padding on the sides is by default `3` so it does not touch the border of the canvas. I wanted it to touch the border of the canvas, and therefore set it to `-3`.

Two different graphs need to be created, one for the left side and one for the right side.
The left graph should have the sidePadding.right set to `-3`. The right graph should have the sidePadding.left set to `-3`.

## Changes in the ChartJS library

I've worked with ChartJS version `v2.9.3`. This method will possibly not work anymore in a new version.

I've changed the following in the `Chart.js` file:

Replace (line number around 11800):

```
// Adjust padding taking into account changes in offsets
// and add 3 px to move away from canvas edges
me.paddingLeft = Math.max((paddingLeft - offsetLeft) * me.width / (me.width - offsetLeft), 0) + 3;
me.paddingRight = Math.max((paddingRight - offsetRight) * me.width / (me.width - offsetRight), 0) + 3;
```

to:

```
// Adjust padding taking into account changes in offsets
// and add 3 px to move away from canvas edges
var layoutOptions = chart.options.layout || {};
var sidePadding = helpers$1.options.toPadding(layoutOptions.sidePadding);
me.paddingLeft = Math.max((paddingLeft - offsetLeft) * me.width / (me.width - offsetLeft), 0) + sidePadding.left;
me.paddingRight = Math.max((paddingRight - offsetRight) * me.width / (me.width - offsetRight), 0) + sidePadding.right;
```

Also you must add the `sidePadding.left` and `sidePadding.right` parameter to ChartJS.

This can be done by changing (line number around 7180):

```
core_defaults._set('global', {
    layout: {
        padding: {
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0
        },
        // Custom added parameter
        sidePadding: {
            left: 3,
            right: 3,
        }
    }
});
```

to:

```
core_defaults._set('global', {
    layout: {
        padding: {
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0
        },
        // Custom added parameter
        sidePadding: {
            left: 3,
            right: 3,
        }
    }
});
```

## Note

This is probably not the best way to achieve this. Changing the ChartJS library is bad-practice and updating the library could revert these changes.

If someone has a better way to achieve this, please post your methods or comment below.